# Looking for a general formula for the sum of n discrete random variables with the same distribution

Tags: probability

I'm having a lot of trouble finding anything I'm able to apply to this specific problem so any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is as follows:

$$X_i\in\text{{0, 1, 1, 2}}\text{, and }S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$$

I need to derive a general formula for:

$$P(S_n=k)\text{, where }k=1, 2, 3,...$$

So basically, I'm supposed to derive a general formula for the sum of $n$ random, independent variables with the same distribution, and I am completely lost here.

The answer is supposed to be:

$$P(S_n=k)={2n \choose k}({1\over2})^{2n}$$

All that is stated to justify this answer is:

$$X_i\text{ has binomial }(2, {1\over2})\text{ distribution, and it follows that }S_n\text{ has binomial }({2n, {1\over2}}) \text{ distribution}$$

How does $X_i$ have a binomial distribution? How are they getting these values for $n$ and $p$ from the distribution of $X_i$? And how does the distribution of $S_n$ follow from the distribution of $X_i$? I'm so confused, please help!

Comment: I assume $X_i \in \{0, 1, 1, 2\}$ means $\Pr\{X_i = 0\} = \Pr\{X_i = 2\} = 1/4, \Pr\{X_i = 1\} = 1/2$. Then it has a $\text{binomial}(2, 1/2)$ distribution. The way to figure out is to note that when $p = 1/2$, all the binomial pmfs are proportional to $1/2^n$, therefore they only differ by the corresponding Binomial coefficient. And it is well known that $\binom {2} {0} = 1, \binom {2} {1} = 2, \binom {2} {2} = 1$ so the pmf will be in the ratio of $1:2:1$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. I'm not sure how I didn't notice, but noticing that {0,1,1,2} is itself, a binomial distribution, seems to be the key "insight" required to make any sense of this question. The rest was pretty straight-forward after realizing that... I feel a bit embarrassed now. Thanks again.